# Why does Bash have both a built-in echo command and standalone echo programs?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, echo

I am using a Bash shell on Ubuntu 22.04.

When I run `type -a echo`, I get the following output:

[image]

What I understand is that when I run a command, let's say `echo "Hello Wolrd!"`, Bash will run the built-in `echo` command. **Am I right**?

**My first  question is**: If Bash runs the built-in `echo` command by default, why there are standalone `echo` programs: `/usr/bin/echo` and `/bin/echo`? Are there specific scenarios when one would prefer to use the standalone programs of `echo`?

**My second question is**: Why there are two standalone programs of `echo`, as shown in the screenshot above? And if I decide to run the standalone program, which one should I use and why?

I would appreciate a detailed answer. Thanks.

**Edit-1**
This is what I get when I run the `readlink` command to check whether `/bin` is a symlink to `/usr/bin`:

[image]

Comment: How would something like `xargs` run `echo` if there were no program for it?

Comment: And what if another shell does not have `echo` as builtin ?

Comment: `Why there are two standalone programs of echo` Please post the output of `readlink -f /usr/bin/echo /bin/echo`

Comment: @KamilCuk Have added the screenshot

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of text. Please add text as text.

Comment: bash does not **have** two commands of this name. It has **one** internal command named `echo`, and of course every executable which happens to have the name `echo`, **and** is in the PATH which **you** define, is also available under this name.  This is how PATH-search is supposed to work. You could ask why Linux provides an executable named `echo` in /usr/bin. This allows any program to use that `echo` without the need for a shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I right?

Yes.

> why there are standalone echo programs

Because you might want to use them.

> Are there specific scenarios when one would prefer to use the standalone programs of echo?

Yes, when you `fork+exec` and want to run `echo`, not `bash`. Like `xargs echo` given in comments. Note that `xargs` with no arguments by default runs `echo`, so kind of `xargs` depends on existence of `echo` executable.

> Why there are two standalone programs of echo, as shown in the screenshot above?

On most systems, `/bin` is a symlink to `/usr/bin` or otherwise. It is the same file.

> which one should I use and why?

Use the one first in `PATH`. Because `PATH` is for choosing what to run.

Answer (score 4):

Bash has only a built-in `echo`.  The `/bin/echo` program in your system is not coming from the Bash package/project.

Bash's echo is only available from within bash. We cannot get the operating system to execute an `echo` program, for instance with the C library `execl` function:

Without a `/bin/echo`, for instance, this cannot work:

```
execl("/bin/echo", "echo", "foo", (char *) NULL);
```

Only this:

```
execl("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", "echo foo", (char *) NULL);
```

But, why would you ever need to exec `/bin/echo`, instead of just using the I/O library of the programming language to dump something to standard output? That's a good question: you wouldn't. The specific example of `/bin/echo` is not a useful program to have other than as a shell built-in. And even that is mostly deprecated.

The main reason why there is a real `echo` command is that, well, POSIX, ahem, echoes my remarks above about exec. [See section 1.6 here](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap01.html#tagtcjh_18) where this requirement is given:

> *However, all of the standard utilities, including the regular built-ins in the table, but not the special built-ins described in Special Built-In Utilities, shall be implemented in a manner so that they can be accessed via the exec family of functions as defined in the System Interfaces volume of POSIX.1-2008 and can be invoked directly by those standard utilities that require it (`env`, `find`, `nice`, `nohup`, `time`, `xargs`).*

This also provides the rationale we are looking for: there are certain utilities which invoke other utilities, like `xargs` and `find`, without the use of a shell: just by the `exec` mechanism. They cannot work with utilities that are built-in only.

In the specific case of `echo`, using it with any of the above commands is not very useful; but POSIX doesn't make an exception for the `echo` utility; if it is offered as a built-in, it must still be also provided in `exec`-able form.

The only utilities that are allowed to exist as built-ins only are those that must necessarily be built-in in order to make sense. And not even all of those, but a subset. For instance `cd` doesn't make sense as an external command, since it doesn't change the directory of the process which executes it; at best it provides an error check whether it is able to change directory. Yet, `cd` is not one of the *Special Built-In Utilities* that can be provided only as built-in utilities; a POSIX system must have an executable `cd` utility.

Comment: I've wondered why `/bin/[` exists. I thought it was just historical legacy. "POSIX made me do it" explains it.